# How to deploy web2py site on IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, web2py

A couple question.

Running web2py on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7.5. Following the official online book I got the site working with 127.0.0.1:8000. But I want to add the website to IIS service so I can access it with subdomain.mydomain.com (got other sites running this way already)

1. IIS requires me to point to the root directory of the website. For web2py, which directory should I point it to?
2. Any tutorial to create IIS 7.5 URL rewrite rule to use with web2py?
3. The [online book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13#Start-as-Windows-service) mentioned "options.py" but I don't seem to have that file anywhere in my web2py directory

Answer (score 2):

1. Point it to the folder that contains the file `web2py.py`.
2. Web2py has a [built-in URL routing capability](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#URL-Rewrite) that you should use in lieu of IIS 7.5 URL Rewrites
3. If you read the page you referenced carefully, you'll notice that the file included with web2py is actually `options_std.py`.  So you would need to copy the file and rename the copy `options.py`.  From the [web2py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13#Start-as-Windows-service):

> You don't need to create "options.py" from scratch since there is already an "options_std.py" in the web2py folder that you can use as a model.
>
> After creating "options.py" in the
>   web2py installation folder, you can
>   install web2py as a service with:
>
> ```
> python web2py.py -W install
> ```
>
> and start/stop the service with:
>
> ```
> python web2py.py -W start
> python web2py.py -W stop
> ```

Finally, if you have more web2py specific questions you'll find a fantastic community and get great support at the [official web2py google groups page](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py).

Comment: I tried for days to look for options._std.py too but when I unzip web2py_win, it doesn't have any option_std.py nor web2py.py. It only has web2py.exe and most of the other files are .pyd. Running web2py.exe would start the server immediately instead of installation.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm running web2py from source on Windows.  I never tried the web2py_win distribution.  I would personally recommend cloning the repository via Mercurial.  If you don't already have Mercurial installed, I'd grab a copy of TortoiseHg (http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/download/index.html) and then clone the web2py repository via `hg clone https://web2py.googlecode.com/hg/ web2py`.  This will give you the latest development version, but you can easily `hg update` to a tagged stable version.